# Блокировка парсера сайтом

Tags: ruby, парсер

Написал парсер сайта на Руби, достает информацию без проблем, но после 30+- обращений сайт блокирует доступ к желаемым страницам и делает переадресацию. Установил задержку, секунд через 30 продолжает парсить, но такой вариант мне не подходит, так как этот процесс затягивается на день. Вроде и куки меняю, и агент, и прокси, но все равно блочит. Подскажите может, как обойти это?

Comment: Использовать прокси сервера

Comment: Не заметил что прокси вы использовали. Попробуйте прикрутить tor

Answer (score 3):

1. Попробуй подменить user agent https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler#Crawler_identification
2. У сайта точно нет API?